# How to UPDATE a column in a table if the column is not NULL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that submit data to a table. The table column is editable by other user except  `received_date` and `gid` . How to make the column skipped during the update script from PHP?

This is the default_table (simplified):

```
gid     received_date     detail     max_number   status
1                NULL       NULL          NULL         1
```

After first input:

```
gid     received_date         detail     max_number   status
1          2017-07-17       Swimsuit            100        1
```

After second and so on input:

```
gid     received_date          detail     max_number   status
1          2017-07-17     Swimsuit XL            250        1
```

is possible something like this:

```
UPDATE t_goods 
IF(t_goods.received_date = NULL){
   SET received_dates = received_date(today_date), detail = detail, max_number = add_stock WHERE gid = gid
}
ELSE{
   SET detail = detail, max_number = add_stock WHERE gid = gid
}
```

note: the query is just a pseudocode.

Comment: Try "is NULL" instead of =

Comment: I believe that's not a valid query. Just a pseudocode.

Comment: you can use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` in the WHERE statement to either do where null, or where is not null

Comment: You should write an actual query using for example `IF` or `IFNULL` and post back if you have any problems.

Comment: my current query is a simple update query.

Comment: So check the manual and give it a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like that.

```
UPDATE t_goods 
SET 
detail = detail, 
max_number = add_stock,
received_date = IF(received_date IS NULL, received_dates,received_date)
WHERE  gid = gid;
```

`IF(received_date IS NULL, received_dates,received_date)` This equation is update new received_dates value if received_date is null, otherwise it will keep received_date as old value.

Comment: the `detail` is updated but not the `received_date`. In the first input the date should be updated because the default value is NULL

Comment: If ```received_date``` is null then it will update otherwise it will keep old.

Comment: Thank you. I misplaced the dates earlier.

Comment: My Pleasure, Enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE t_goods SET received_dates = NOW(), detail = x, max_number = add_stock WHERE gid = gid AND t_goods.received_date IS NULL;
```

It's hard to understand with out more information, how about this?

Comment: This will only do the first update and not a second or so more updates

Comment: I am only updating one row. not the entire row. so, if the received_date in the updated row is not null then skip it.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, down voting me when your question really lacked detail is kind of sucky, each to there own. Read the manual next time.